# How can I find out which site a particular chat room is associated with

Tags: support, chat

Chat rooms are created with a particular site as parent, or with SE as parent (ie no affiliation at all) but when trying to look through chat rooms to see who should have what kind of access I have not been able to find an easy way to identify the parent site.

Is there a quick/easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310753/152859) is for the case you're already inside a room.

If you're looking in the lobby, i.e. list of chat rooms, the parent site icon appears in the top right, below the favorite star icon:

> [image: parent site icons in chat rooms list]

Unlike the in-room icon it's not a link, but it has a tooltip with the site full name.

Answer (score 2):

All chat rooms have a logo in the footer, for example this one from Security Stack Exchange's chat room:

[image]